# Error CSRF token mismatch aún enviándolo por ajax en Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Tengo el error `CSRF token mismatch.` al recibir respuesta de mi controlador pero envío el token explícitamente por mi método put en ajax a un controlador de Laravel 8 y en la solicitud sale el código y el nombre `_token`, por lo cuál no entiendo por qué tengo el error, tal como lo envio ahora en mi metodo `PUT/PATCH`, lo envié a mi método post y get igualmente a un controlador en Laravel sin error ninguno, no entiendo por qué ahora en `PUT/PATCH` me sale error.

En el siguiente código obtengo todos los datos del formulario que lo tengo en un modal, como se ve en el código ocupo sintaxis blade con la protección `@csrf`.

En el debugger aparece que se envía el token pero recibo por respuesta como si no lo obtuviera o nose si sea por la solicitud PUT/PATCH.

**Código Ajax Para Actualizar**

```
$(document).on('submit', '#editUserInformation', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let sendId = $('#editId').val();
        // console.log(sendId);
        let editData = new FormData(this);
        editData.append('description', `${$('#editDescriptionEditor').summernote('code')}`);

        $.ajax({
            url        : 'http://davidpaucar.com/admin/user/' + sendId,
            method     : 'put',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data       : editData,
            success    : function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    });
```

[image: datos de la petición]

[image: respuesta con el error]

Este código funciona [X-CSRF-TOKEN](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) pero en toda mi aplicación ocupo la forma del Ajax por lo que no quisiera cambiar todo de nuevo, ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer la solicitud `PUT/PATCH` tenía un inconveniente al enviar mis datos, lo solucioné agregando el siguiente código a mi solicitud la cuál la procesa como `POST` en lugar de `PUT/PATCH`.

[Referencia de la solución al realizar peticiones ajax con PUT/PATCH](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-fix-csrf-token-mismatch-for-patch-ajax-request-2nd-time)

Esta línea hará que laravel maneje mi llamado como `PUT/PATCH`

```
editData.append('_method', 'PUT');
```

Y esta línea procesará la solicitud por el llamado POST con la información del formulario.

```
method     : 'post',
```

El código final de la solución sería el siguiente.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#editUserInformation', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let sendId = $('#editId').val();
        // console.log(sendId);
        let editData = new FormData(this);
        editData.append('description', `${$('#editDescriptionEditor').summernote('code')}`);
        editData.append('_method', 'PUT');
        // for (var key of editData.entries()) {
        //     console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
        // }
        $.ajax({
            url        : 'http://davidpaucar.com/admin/user/' + sendId,
            method     : 'post',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data       : editData,
            success    : function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    });
```